# How to select one child div by clicking on another child div of the same parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

For example I have simple html.

```
<body>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="child"></div> <!-- div element I click -->
        <div class="childINeedToSelect"></div> <!-- div element I need to be selected -->
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="childINeedToSelect"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click on top first `child` class div I need to change, for example, border **ONLY** of the first `childINeedToSelect` class div. They have the same parent - `a` class div, but the difficult is that there are more than just one element with class `a`. I've already tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var child = $('.child');
    child.bind('click', function() {
        detectElement($(this));
    });
});

var belt;
function detectElement(arrow) {
    belt = arrow.parent('.a').children('childINeedToSelect').eq(1);
    belt.css("background-color", "red");
}
```

As you see I'm trying to send `$(this)` as parameter to `detectElement()` to determine which div was clicked. But my target `div` background doesn't change, and when I try to use element `belt` later, after it was *detected* by `detectElement()` function, Opera javascript debugger gives me error

```
Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'belt.css('marginLeft')' to object
```

in line

```
var currentMargin = parseInt(belt.css('marginLeft').toString().replace('px', ''));
```

but this line of code worked perfectly, before calling `detectElement()` function; What am I doing wrong? How should I select element I need?

Comment: belt = arrow.parent('.a').children('childINeedToSelect').eq(1); is not   a valid selectore, only one object there, so it's .eq(0), but you don't even need the EQ with this selector pattern....

Comment: also `children('childINeedToSelect')` is missing dot prefix to denote class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function detectElement(arrow) {
    arrow.parent().find('.childINeedToSelect').css('background-color','red');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.child').click(function(){
        detectElement($(this));
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lq9ZD/).

Or you could use the `nextAll()` method to find the sibling `childINeedToSelect`:

```
function detectElement(arrow) {
    arrow.nextAll('.childINeedToSelect').css('background-color','red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lq9ZD/1/).

And if you should have multiple `.child` and `childINeedToSelect` elements, you can pass the `:first` selector into the `nextAll()` method:

```
function detectElement(arrow) {
    arrow.nextAll('.childINeedToSelect:first').css('background-color','red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lq9ZD/2/).

I'm unsure why you were using `bind()`, but on the off-chance that you *might* be trying to account for dynamically-added elements (added *after* the event-handlers are bound to the various DOM nodes/jQuery objects), you could instead use `on()`:

```
$('.a').on('click','.child', function(){
    detectElement($(this));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lq9ZD/3/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7urq8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var child = $('.child');
    child.bind('click', function() {
        detectElement($(this));
    });
});

var belt;
function detectElement(arrow) {
    belt = arrow.siblings('.childINeedToSelect').eq(0);
    belt.css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
jQuery('.a').children().first().click(function(){
jQuery('.childINeedToSelect').attr('background-color','red');
)}
```